# How to get ByteData from a File

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to convert a `File` to a `ByteData` object in flutter.
Something like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
File file = getSomeCorrectFile(); //This file is correct
ByteData bytes = ByteData(file.readAsBytesSync()); //Doesnt compile
return bytes;
```

I understood that `ByteData` constructor receives the length of the amount of bytes and initialize them with 0, so I could do something like `ByteData(file.readAsBytesStync().length);` but then how do I fill them?
What am I missing?

Comment: what do you need that `ByteData` for?

Comment: @pskink I have an API library that receives a ByteData and post it to a server. I could change this library but on my particular case is not simple

Comment: but what if that file is 1GB long? would you like to read it all?

Comment: so this code will do that: `File('/some/file/to/read').openRead().listen((list) {
                  ByteData data = Uint8List.fromList(list).buffer.asByteData(); // do something with 'data'
                });`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Dart 2.5.0 or later, I believe that the following should work:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

...
File file = getSomeCorrectFile();
Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
return ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
```

(Prior to Dart 2.5.0, the `file.readAsBytesSync()` line should be:

```dart
Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync() as Uint8List;
```

[`File.readAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html)/[`File.readAsBytesSync`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-io/File/readAsBytesSync.html) used to be declared to return a `List<int>`, but [the returned object was actually a `Uint8List` subtype](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31547).)

Once you have the bytes as a `Uint8List`, you can [extract its `ByteBuffer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.1/dart-typed_data/TypedData/buffer.html) and construct a `ByteData` from that.

Answer (score 11):

in Dart 2.9:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

final file = getSomeCorrectFile(); // File
final bytes = await file.readAsBytes(); // Uint8List
final byteData = bytes.buffer.asByteData(); // ByteData

return byteData;
```

Answer (score 5):

this is worked for me ...

```
  Uint8List uint8list = Uint8List.fromList(File(path).readAsBytesSync())
```

Comment: This works but is inefficient since it creates an unnecessary copy of a potentially large `Uint8List`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File file = getSomeCorrectFile(); 
ByteData bytes = await file.readAsBytes().then((data) => ByteData.view(data as ByteBuffer)); 
return bytes;
```

Comment: Mixing `await` and `Future.then` is bad style; it's unnecessary and just makes your code more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

here is my class to handle this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class FileHandler {
    final String _filePath;
    FileHandler(this._filePath);
    Future<Uint8List> _readToBytes() async {
         var file = File.fromUri(Uri.parse(_filePath));
         return await file.readAsBytes();
    }

    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get data async {
        var byte = await _readToBytes();
        var ext = _filePath.split('.').last;
        return {'byte': byte, 'extension': ext};
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

here is my class to handle this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class FileHandler {
    final String _filePath;
    FileHandler(this._filePath);
    Future<Uint8List> _readToBytes() async {
         var file = File.fromUri(Uri.parse(_filePath));
         return await file.readAsBytes();
    }

    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get data async {
        var byte = await _readToBytes();
        var ext = _filePath.split('.').last;
        return {'byte': byte, 'extension': ext};
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908289/.