# Image to ByteData conversion showing error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, root

I am trying to covert a File to ByteData. It is working fine for iOS but showing error for Android.

It is showing below error:

```
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.ABS.test_app/cache/image_picker8022762310279398302.jpg
```

Here is my code:

```
Future<Null> init() async {
    try {   
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(widget.fileImage.path);
      image = await loadImage(Uint8List.view(data.buffer));         
    } catch (e) {
      print('load image Error -- $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
image = await loadImage(bytes);
```

I got reference from the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044473/how-to-get-bytedata-from-a-file)